# Will unmounting a partition erase the info stored there?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mount, umount

I have a question about installing Ubuntu on an already partitioned drive. 
I have 3 partitions - 1 for music & pictures, 1 for gaming and 1 for my operating system. When I go to install Ubuntu after setting up the appropriate partitions within the partition for the operating system, I get the message that it needs to unmount an existing partition (my gaming partition) in order to proceed. 
Will unmounting that partition delete the information stored there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, partition was probably automaticly mounted - so, umounting it doesn't remove anything. You can safe umount it and remount it in other place.

Comment: Okay. Is it pretty self explanatory once I allow it to unmount?

Comment: you can umount it end then proceed instalation. remeber to don't check this partition to format during install.

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not delete the data.  You can remount the volume on another directory and all of your data will be there.

Comment: Okay good. Is it pretty self explanatory once I allow it to unmount? I'm just so afraid of loosing all my data.

Comment: Not certain if it will automatically remount the partition afterwards, I guess it depends on why it needs to unmount it in the first place!  Shout for help if it doesn't.